# Como identificar problemas relacionados com datas (ex: 2014-03-03)

Tags: debate, tags

Quando queremos aplicar uma tag que indique que o problema a ser resolvido está relacionado com datas (2014-03-03), não podemos usar a tag [datas] pois existe uma tag [data], mas mesmo que não existisse, não sei se vai existir alguma confusão.

Como podemos referenciar que um problema diz respeito a datas mas não propriamente um Unix Timestamp, de forma a não surgirem confusões?

**Nota:**
A tag [data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) está vazia e sem perguntas relacionadas. Alguém vê algum uso na nossa língua para a mesma ou podemos ficar com as tags [data] e [datas] para indicar assuntos relativos a datas de calendário ?

Comment: Tem uma tag datetime, se não me engano.

Comment: @bfavaretto Mas datetime é igual a '2014-03-03 18:09:30', ou seja, é especifica a esse formato. _(penso eu que a ideia será essa)_

Answer (score 3):

Hoje a tag [datetime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datetime) tem uma descrição bastante ampla, que acaba englobando o significado de data/datas:

> Um objeto DateTime em muitas linguagens de programação descreve uma data e uma hora do dia. Pode expressar qualquer instante no tempo ou uma posição sobre um calendário, dependendo do contexto em que é usada e da aplicação específica.

Porém concordo que "datetime" não seja um bom nome para a tag genérica. Acho que poderíamos sim usar [data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data) para isso (já tem uma pergunta com ela, inclusive), e definir "datas", no plural, como sinônimo.

Quanto a uma tag "dado" ou "dados", acho ampla demais para ser útil. A tag equivalente no SO tem 10k perguntas, mas o wiki dela diz que seria melhor usar algo mais específico...

Comment: Penso que será o caminho a seguir, vamos aguardar por mais feedback.

Comment: Vamos precisar de um retag manual da maioria das perguntas de datetime.

Answer (score 0):

O SO original aceita várias tags relativas a tempo que permitem tratamento individual de cada tipo, como por exemplo [Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetime/info), [Date](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/date/info), [Time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/time/info) e [Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timestamp/info).

[Data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/data/info), por sua vez, significa dado. Não sei se isso causaria algum tipo de overlap com o sentido em português de tempo; acredito que não.

Assim sendo, podemos ter as seguintes correlações:

- Datetime: `data-e-hora` (ou `data-e-horário`)
- Date: `Data`
- Data: `Dado`
- Time: `Horário`; e, o pior de todos,
- Timestamp: `Carimbo-de-data-e-horário`

(Eu adotaria `Carimbo-de-data-e-horário` só para ter uma tag verborrágica e ver onde o CSS quebra.)

Mas, da mesma maneira que não mudamos a tag [Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) para `Andróide`, fica a pergunta: Qual é o limite do esforço de tradução? Até onde ele pode ir sem perder a conexão semântica com o conteúdo original?

Uma coisa é criar respostas informativas em português, mas nenhuma das linguagens que conheço permite, para fins práticos, que você mude algo tão fundamental como o nome de um tipo de dado nativo.

`Data`, entretanto, não é um tipo de dado. Eu sugeriria, neste caso, *preservar os nomes de tipos de dado*, e criar apelidos traduzidos para com o objetivo de permitir buscas contextuais. `Data`, assim, poderia ser o apelido de `Date`.

Comment: A minha duvida é mesmo isso, vamos traduzir coisas como timestamp? Penso que não (algures isso foi discutido @bfavaretto). Mas relativamente a `data` e `datas` irá ser lido no futuro como algo referentes a dias de calendário e suas variantes ou vai ser lido como usualmente empregado em Inglês `data` AKA `dados` _!?_